# Update a DataGridView using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linq

In the process of answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48393340/simulate-ctrl-down-until-i-desire-in-c/48393804#48393804), I wrote some code to save and restore the selection state of the cells within a DataGridView. The idea is to save the state then re-apply it after the user clicks within the grid, in order to imitate "sticky selection" functionality that DataGridView doesn't normally provide. The solution I wrote works fine.

As an exercise for myself, I decided to rewrite some of the code to use LINQ and fluent syntax. Also, I think fluent syntax looks pretty :) You can get the DataGridView to work with LINQ [with the `Cast<>` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098071/how-can-i-use-linq-to-find-a-datagridview-row). My first job was saving the selection state:

Before:

```
static private bool[][] GetSelectionState(DataGridView input)
{
    int rowCount = input.Rows.Count;
    int columnCount = input.Columns.Count;
    var result = new bool[rowCount][];
    for (var r = 0; r < rowCount; r++)
    {
        result[r] = new bool[columnCount];
        for (var c = 0; c < columnCount; c++)
        {
            var cell = input.Rows[r].Cells[c];
            result[r][c] = cell.Selected;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

After (with LINQ):

```
static private bool[][] GetSelectionState(DataGridView grid)
{
    return grid
        .Rows
        .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
        .Select
        (
            r => r.Cells
                .Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
                .Select(c => c.Selected)
                .ToArray()
        )
        .ToArray();
}
```

That part works fine too.

But I am having trouble applying the state back to the DataGridView. I know this isn't exactly in keeping with the spirit of LINQ (I think it is more meant for a functional/immutable type of programming approach). But I thought I could trick it by using `Zip` to line up the cells with the stored selection state and apply it with a simple assignment operation. Here is what I came up with.

Before:

```
static private void SetSelectionState(DataGridView input, bool[][] selectionState)
{
    for (int r = 0; r <= selectionState.GetUpperBound(0); r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c <= selectionState[r].GetUpperBound(0); c++)
        {
            input.Rows[r].Cells[c].Selected = selectionState[r][c];
        }
    }
}
```

After (with LINQ-- **this is the problem**):

```
static private void SetSelectionState(DataGridView grid, IEnumerable<IEnumerable<bool>> selectionState)
{
    grid.Rows
        .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
        .Zip
        (
            selectionState, 
            (row, rowState) => row
                .Cells
                .Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
                .Zip
                (
                    rowState, 
                    (cell, cellState) => cell.Selected = cellState 
                )
        )
        .ToList();  //Purge enumerator
}
```

^This compiles and runs, ***but when it is finished, the*** `Selected` ***property is set to false for every cell.***

I also tried replacing

```
.Zip
(
    rowState, 
    (cell, cellState) => cell.Selected = cellState
)
```

...with...

```
.Zip
(
    rowState, 
    (cell, cellState) => 
    {
        cell.Selected = cellState; 
        return cellState; 
    }
)
```

...and also...

```
.Zip
(
    rowState, 
    (cell, cellState) => 
    {
        grid.Rows[cell.RowIndex].Cells[cell.ColumnIndex].Selected = cellState;
        return cellState; 
    }
)
```

..but with the same results.

Is it possible to use LINQ in this fashion, to update a control's properties from a zipped jagged array? Or is it impossible because LINQ treats everything as immutable, and makes copies of everything?  Is there some other "LINQ-y" way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the enumerator that drives the inner `Zip` call was not being exercised, due to deferred execution. I resolved the issue by adding `Last` to the end of each resultset, ensuring that the enumerator will be run to its conclusion, and that resolved the issue.

```
static private void SetSelectionState(DataGridView grid, IEnumerable<IEnumerable<bool>> selectionState)
{
    grid.Rows
        .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
        .Zip
        (
            selectionState,
            (row, rowState) => row.Cells
                .Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
                .Zip
                (
                    rowState,
                    (cell, cellState) => cell.Selected = cellState
                )
                .Last()
        )
        .Last();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

personally I would leave `SetSelectionState` as-is: with two nested `for` loops.

it is more clear and portable (Linq is .net-specific, `for` is universal)

if I needed enumerable version, I would iterate over array, using Select and SelectMany overloads with indices, and use those indices to access DataGridView cells:

```
private void SetSelectionState(DataGridView grid, bool[][] selectionState)
{
    selectionState.SelectMany((bool[] array, int row) => 
                              array.Select((bool state, int column) =>
                                           grid[column, row].Selected = state))
                  .Last(); // forces projection
}
```

or use RowIndex and ColumnIndex properties of a DataGridViewCell

```
private void SetSelectionState(DataGridView grid, bool[][] selectionState)
{
    grid.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
        .SelectMany(r => r.Cells.OfType<DataGridViewCell>())
        .Select(c => c.Selected = selectionState[c.RowIndex][c.ColumnIndex])
        .Last();
}
```